# How to use a form from a component in another component

Tags: angularjs, forms, components

I have a form controller and a table controller, in my table I have a edit button, when I clicked this button my pop need to show up and update my user in table. How I do this? How I use form from his component in my table component?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a way of passing data between controllers (Table Controller and the Form Controller). In this case, you need to introduce a service that keeps the value of the clicked item in your table list - this service should have both the "set" method and the "get" method. Your Table Controller sets the value and your Form Controller can simply read the value and populate its fields according.

Somewhere in your Table Controller:

```
$scope.selectItem = function (item){
        console.log("Selected Item ", item);
        //we indicate to our ItemsService that this is the current item
        ItemsService.setSelectedItem(item);        
        //switch to item-view form (which will then use the ItemsService to get the selected item)
        $location.path("/form");
      };
```

Somewhere in your Form Controller:

```
var selectedItem = ItemsService.getSelectedItem();
      console.log("Got Item Selected From List :: ", selectedItem, "");
      //this is how we load it on the "details form"
      $scope.formData = selectedItem;
```

This is a fairly common use case for most applications - I have created a basic AngularJS project that demonstrates this - you can try and follow it and see if this.  See my [angularjs-list-details-tutorial](https://github.com/ishmaelmakitla/angularjs-list-details-tutorial).

I hope this helps.

Comment: And how I open the form in table component?

Comment: You use the $location service and specify the path - or if you want a modal form, then you can look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/rnkoaa/8333940

Comment: I already have a form, I want to use this form from component.

Comment: So the form is on a template - and you have a controller for this template? You could use the same approach  - refer to the form using $scope - I think it will be more helpful if you edit your question and include your code. Show us what you have done.